# What does "flash.profiler.profile" do?

Tags: actionscript-3

I found the undocumented function named `profile` in the package `flash.profiler` that receive a `Boolean` parameter.

What does it do?

Comment: [Looks like you wouldn't be the first to ask.](https://www.mail-archive.com/flexcomponents@yahoogroups.com/msg01513.html)

Comment: Yep, unfortunately this question don't have an answer too... :(

Comment: "The **flash.profiler** package contains functions used for debugging and profiling ActionScript code." It is pretty much possible that this property allows environments (like FlashDevelop) and/or tools (like Scout) connect and profile the running AS3 applications. The fact it is not officially documented (probably) means that it has no apparent use in pure AS3 environment.

Comment: @Organis, where did you find this description? I had seen something like this before... [Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/profiler/package.html)?

Comment: @biio Official documentation. The first place to look when you're dealing with AS3: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/profiler/package-detail.html